# Boost.log - Get current file name when using file rotation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I know that this question may be a duplicate but I want to know whether there is still no possibility to get the current log file name when there is a file backend with filename rotation?!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

With filename rotation I mean something like the following where the filename changes when the log file gets rotated:

```
auto fileSink = logging::add_file_log(
    keywords::file_name = "..\\Logs\\%Y%m%d_Tracing_%H%M%S.log",
    keywords::rotation_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::min_free_space = 15 * 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app);
```

Comment: It's a property of the backend. If you use the `add_file_log` from utility/setup/file.hpp then you never see the backend. Instead you just get the `sink` which is probably what you need 80% of the time. I looked at [`aux::add_file_log` implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp) but it looks strongly like the backed is left undocumented on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) mentioned:

> It's a property of the backend.

Therefor I managed to separate the sink initialization from the corresponding backend:

```
typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_file_backend> fileSink;
boost::shared_ptr<fileSink> fileSinkSink;
fileSinkSink = logging::add_file_log(
    keywords::file_name = "..\\Logs\\%Y%m%d_Tracing_%H%M%S.log",
    keywords::rotation_size = 2* 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::min_free_space = 15 * 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app);
```

Now I figured out that I can access the backend and thereby the current file name:

```
char currentFileName[200] = "";
strcpy(currentFileName, fileSinkSink->locked_backend().get()->get_current_file_name().string().c_str());
```

Thanks for that hint! It solved my problem!